# Create my own pre-name like "std" in C++

Tags: c++, namespaces

Generally when somebody creates a console program he writes

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    std::cout<<"hello world"<<std::endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

The `std` must be included to call `cout` and `endl` statements.

When I create a library using the headers and the code in the `.h` and `.cpp`, and then I include that library, I must use the name of functions/clases/structs/etc directly. How can I make it so I have to use a pre-word like the `std` for `cout` and `endl`?

Comment: They're called *namespaces*.

Comment: It's called a `namespace`.

Comment: Oh I should mention it as well: they are called **namespaces.**

Comment: @user2597243: If you are asking this kind of question (not knowing the name), I take it you should really start reading a good C++ introductory book before going any further. Please consult [this SO list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: I've updated your title; it's `std`, not `STD`. (C++ is case-sensitive, so it matters.)

Answer (score 4):

It's called a *namespace*.

You can declare your own stuff inside a namespace like this:

```
namespace mystuff
{
    int foo();
}
```

To define:

```
int mystuff::foo()
{
    return 42;
}
```

To use:

```
int bar = mystuff::foo();
```

Or, import a namespace, just like you can do with `std` if you don't want to fully-qualify everything:

```
using namespace mystuff;
// ...
int bar = foo();
```

Answer (score 0):

you must define namespace like this

```
namespace mynamespace {
    class A{
        int func(){
        }
    }
    void func2(){}
}
```

you can import namespace like this

```
using namespace mynamespace;
```

Answer (score 0):

STD prefix is a namespace.

to define/declare a namespace you can follow that example:

```
namespace test
{ int f(); };
```

f belong to the namspace test.
to call f you can

```
test::f();

or

using namespace test;
 ....
 f();
```